# Corece to boolean in Common Lisp

Tags: boolean, common-lisp, coercion

Is there a build-in function in Common Lisp to coerce any thing into it's boolean value, like the `bool` function in Python does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing specifically for this. You can't use `boolean` as the type argument to `coerce`. You can use:

```
(defun boolean-value (x)
  (not (not x)))
```

This is analogous to the `!!x` idiom used in many other languages.

Comment: I've seen the equivalent `(not (null x))` more often as idiom, but both work.

Comment: Me, too, I just didn't want to open up the "what's the difference between `NOT` and `NULL`" can of worms.

Comment: ... so what is the difference?

Comment: @Mattwmaster58 There's no operational difference. The difference to programmers is that `NOT` is for logical testing, while `NULL` is for structural testing.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.  `(and form t)` will return `t` if `form` is not one of the false values `nil` or `()`.

*I.e.* it is a macro, not a function, and it requires the additional argument `t` to do the trick.